# Some windows don't receive mouse events (windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mouse-click

I have a strange problem. Some windows don't receive mouse clicks. For e.g. the virtualbox window or "pdf split and merge". The buttons in this windows are not clickable. I installed a click counter and this software count the clicks so the windows just don't receive the corresponding events. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Edit: It seams that only (or mostly) QT software is affected.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a problem with the specific software from what it sounds like, or you have some external program / virus interfering to prevent it

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with the specific software because so much software is affected. E.g VLC, Virtualbox, Teamspeak ... . Is there a way to find the interfering software?

Comment: Well you could look at what is running in task manager or starting up in msconfig.. narrow down to things you know what are running

Comment: I used Prozess Explorer, hijackthis and msconfig and didn't see any software that should not be there. I did a scann with a anti-virus tool and it did not encountered anything. If it is a virus, than it hides very well.